# CKEditor: how to fix Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': An object could not be cloned?

Tags: ckeditor

I try implement upload image CKEditor 4.6 C# Error:

```
VM57:25 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': An object could not be cloned.
    at blockWindow (<anonymous>:25:16)
    at window.open (<anonymous>:34:9)
    at a.popup (http://localhost:8842/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:813:59)
    at button.m [as onClick] (http://localhost:8842/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:814:157)
    at button.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8842/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:538:194)
    at button.p (http://localhost:8842/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:10:224)
    at button.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (http://localhost:8842/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:12:47)
    at button.click (http://localhost:8842/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:537:264)
    at CKEDITOR.dom.element.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8842/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:529:40)
    at CKEDITOR.dom.element.p (http://localhost:8842/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:10:224)
```

How to fix? please

Comment: I only use file ckeditor.js. Why duplicate?

Comment: Error occur: parent.postMessage({
            type: "safeBlock",
            url: args[0],
            args: args,
            href: target ? target.href : null
        }, window._parent);

Comment: I'd submit an new issue [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/issues), it looks like there's been some recent DOM fixes https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/blob/master/CHANGES.md